# Can you run to perform a non-required mitzvah on Shabbos/Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, women, yom-tov

I have heard from many sources that running is prohibited on Shabbos unless one is running to do a mitzvah, i.e. toward shul for davening. However, could one run--on Shabbos or Yom Tov--to perform a mitzvah in which one is not strictly obligated? I am thinking of--possibly--running to maariv, or, for a woman, running to any positive mitzvah that is not required of her and for which she does not have a chazaka, such as davening in shul per se, or the second kiddush.

Related: [Can You Run On Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43568/can-you-run-on-shabbos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rav Aharon Mazuz from Yeshivat Kisei Rachamim](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/4632) was asked the following question:
Is the permission to run on Shabbos for a mitzvah relevant if there is a reason for it like trying to be one of the first ten in synagogue or is it alright to run for a mitzvah on Shabbos in all cases.

The Rav answers:

> הרב המשיב: הרב אהרן מאזוז שליט"א.
>   1. עצם מה שאדם רץ לדבר מצוה יש בו מצוה ולכך רשאי לרוץ לדבר מצוה אף בשבת בכל אופן. וכמו שאמרו בגמרא ברכות (דף ו' עמוד ב') לעולם ירוץ אדם
>   לדבר מצוה (כן גרסת הרי"ף) ואפילו בשבת שנאמר אחרי ה' ילכו כארי ישאג וגו
>
> The very fact that a person runs for a mitzvah is in itself a mitzvah
>   and therefore it is allowed to run for a mitzvah on Shabbos in every
>   case as it says in the Gemara Berakhot 6b, “One should always run for
>   a mitzvah (that's the text of the Rif) and even on Shabbos as the
>   verse Hoshea 11 (10) says “They shall go (run?) after the Lord: He
>   shall roar like a lion.”

So it seems that it is a mitzvah to run on Shabbos after any mitzvah.